# Prevent expansion of quotes and other special characters when printing XML using RapidXML

Tags: rapidxml

I am using RapidXML to read an XML file, parse it, do some operation and write it back.

Any text written in quotes within tag, is printed with quotes in expanded form.

Is there any flag that will prevent expansion of quotes and other special characters.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this will work. Writing the XML is unrelated to how it was created, and changing the parse flags would not affect it.

The whole point of printing XML DOM is to create a well-formed XML that can later be parsed; therefore, I wouldn't expect an XML library to have such an option.

If you want such functionality, you can easily write one by changing the function `copy_and_expand_chars` in `rapidxml_print.hpp`

Comment: i used fastest and the ugliest way... commented out character expansion part of "copy_and_expand_chars" function. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to turn off entity translation during parsing. Can you try by setting the [`parse_no_entity_translation`](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_7223b7815c4fb8b42e6e4e77e1ea6b97_17223b7815c4fb8b42e6e4e77e1ea6b97) flag during parsing?

Comment: I used doc.parse<parse_full | parse_no_entity_translation>(buff); but quotes are still expanded as & q u o t ;